# How to use to get substring according to pattern in shell script without XML parser

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Below is the command used for getting the required string from the file.

```
cat xmlconfig.new |grep "id=\"build\""
```

> < parameter id="build" >v6.0.9< /parameter >

I want the v6.0.9 value from the above result, in such a way that it tokenizes according to the bracket, not according to word position

I do not have xml parser installed on my machine and I do not have admin access

I want to know if it can be done without using XML parser

Comment: Use an XML parser. There are a million other questions that show you how to do that.

Comment: @TomFenech Cannot it be done with any bash command? My machine does not have xml parser installed that is the reason I asked about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper XML parser, e.g. [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh):

```
open xmlconfig.new ;
echo //parameter[@id='build'] ;
```

Comment: Is there any other way other than XML parser. I do not have xml parser installed on my machine and I do not have admin access

Comment: You don't need admin access to install tools for yourself.

Comment: For some reason or restrictions, I am unable to do that. That is why I needed to ask this question

Comment: @TinyJaguar: Then explain to the people who placed the restrictions why you need a parser.